# I'm trying to figure out how to fix the drain under the bathtub

Tags: plumbing, bathroom, drain, bathtub

My house was built 1974. I recently started a bathroom remodel. I have been fighting with getting the bathtub level and the problem was the drain and overflow assembly was keeping the tub from going down any further. So I'm just going to change it.

Well the long extension below the tee on the old brass one has been soldered in the drain hole. So the new one can not be installed. Even if i get it out i think it will still be too high. I've looked everywhere online and can't find any info on this type of plumbing. I'm stuck. Well can't seem to figure out how to add a picture. But the pipe has joints with a big rubber ring around it in front of each joint. This is in a concrete slab in South Louisiana. Also one of the joints is loose.

Comment: Can you post a picture of the drain you're talking about? It would help you get answers to your question